# wordpress built-in Jalali date convertor

Tags: functions, date, date-time

I'm developing a new plugin for a client and he wants dates to be in Jalali. As I changed language of WordPress to Persian, the posts date automatically changed to Jalali. So I Think maybe WordPress has some built-in functions for Jalali dates, But couldn't find anything in the internet. Can some one confirm if it's true? If it's true, can you link related documents?

Comment: The dates in Persian Language are coming from the built-in Persian Language Pack. ([Ref](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/)). What exactly are you looking for? Showing the dates in Local Time?

Comment: @Abhik I want to get datetime from database and return it as Jalali date in a template file.

Comment: Just get the date and print it on frontend, it will be in Jalai since the language is already set as Persian.

Comment: @Abhik I get it directly from database and I can't get it by some functions like `the_date()` and when I do it, I get the date in Gregorian.